# How to handle this deprecated event?

Tags: javascript, events, deprecated

I'm a starter and not sure how I should write this piece of code properly, since 'event' seems deprecated.

```
input.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
   if (event.keyCode === 13) {
     event.preventDefault();
     button.click();
 }
 })
```

Comment: If this is Javascript, please add a `javascript` tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You missed an *event* in the callback

```
input.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
   if (event.keyCode === 13) {
     event.preventDefault();
     button.click();
   }
})
```

Comment: Then VS marks 'keyCode' as deprecated.

Comment: @MarcZwiers That's a different question. Take a look at the [documentation for event.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) for guidance